# Repetindo a subtração de grupos em um data frame para todas as variáveis numéricas

Tags: r, dataframe

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
 df <- data.frame(grp = rep(letters[1:3], each = 2), 
                     index = rep(1:2, times = 3), 
                     value = seq(10, 60, length.out = 6),
                     value2 = seq(20, 70, length.out = 6),
                     value3 = seq(30, 80, length.out = 6))

library(tidyverse)
tbl_df(df) #para melhor visualização

# grp   index value value2 value3
# <fct> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 a      1    10     20     30
# 2 a      2    20     30     40
# 3 b      1    30     40     50
# 4 b      2    40     50     60
# 5 c      1    50     60     70
# 6 c      2    60     70     80

# resultado esperado:
# grp   index value value2 value3
# <fct> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 a      1    10     20     30
# 2 a      2    20     30     40
# 3 b      1   -20    -20    -20
# 4 b      2   -20    -20    -20
# 5 c      1    50     60     70
# 6 c      2    60     70     80

# subtrair um grupo de outro
df$value[df$grp=="b"]  = df$value[df$grp=="b"]  - df$value[df$grp=="c"]
df$value2[df$grp=="b"] = df$value2[df$grp=="b"] - df$value2[df$grp=="c"]
df$value3[df$grp=="b"] = df$value3[df$grp=="b"] - df$value3[df$grp=="c"]
```

Como subtraio todos os *value#* do grupo 'c' dos *value#* do grupo 'b', de uma vez, sem a necessidade de repetir

```
df$value[df$grp=="b"]  = df$value[df$grp=="b"]  - df$value[df$grp=="c"]
```

para cada variável?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O seguinte faz o que quer com R base.

```
ib <- which(df$grp == "b")
ic <- which(df$grp == "c")
df[3:5] <- lapply(df[3:5], function(x){
  x[ib] <- x[ib] - x[ic]
  x
})

df
#  grp index value value2 value3
#1   a     1    10     20     30
#2   a     2    20     30     40
#3   b     1   -20    -20    -20
#4   b     2   -20    -20    -20
#5   c     1    50     60     70
#6   c     2    60     70     80
```

Agora, arruma-se a casa. As variáveis `ib` e `ic` usadas para indexar os vetores a transformar já não são necessárias.

```
rm(ib, ic)
```

Answer (score 2):

É possível fazer assim com `dplyr`:

```
bind_rows(
  df %>% 
    filter(grp == "a"),

  df %>% 
    filter(grp != "a") %>% 
    group_by(index) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(starts_with("value")), funs(. - lead(., order_by = grp, default = 0)))
)

  grp index value value2 value3
1   a     1    10     20     30
2   a     2    20     30     40
3   b     1   -20    -20    -20
4   b     2   -20    -20    -20
5   c     1    50     60     70
6   c     2    60     70     80
```

O código fica meio estranho pq existe o grupo A. Se na prática vc sempre subtraisse o valor do grupo anterior pelo valor do próximo grupo poderia ignorar o bind_rows e filtros.